# Getting segmentation fault when trying to create an object

Tags: c++, pointers, object, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a Node object. But I am getting segmentation fault. I don't what I am doing wrong. Here is my code -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define MAX 1000
#define THRESHOLD 2
using namespace std;

class Node{
    int val, fr;
    Node* link;
    public:
        Node(){
            this->link = NULL;
        }
        void set_val(int val){
            this->val = val;
        }
        void set_fr(int fr){
            this->fr = fr;
        }
        void set_link(Node* link){
            this->link = link;
        }
        Node* get_link(){
            return this->link;
        }
        void inc_fr(){
            this->fr++;
        }
        int get_val() const{
            return this->val;
        }
        int get_fr() const{
            return this->fr;
        }
};

void increment(list<Node> &nodes, int &value);
bool compare(const Node& first, const Node& second);
void print_list(list<int> a);
void print_node(Node a);
void prune(list<Node> &nodes, list<int> &values);
void sort_list(list<Node> &nodes, list<int> &values);
int get_fr(list<Node> nodes, int val);
void insert_into_tree(map< Node*,list<Node*> > &tree, map< int, Node* > &header, Node* head, list<int> values);
bool find_head(map< Node*,list<Node*> > tree, Node* head);

int main(){
    fstream file("my.txt");
    string s;
    int check[MAX] = {0};
    list<Node> nodes;
    map< Node*, list<Node*> > tree;
    map< int, Node* > header;
    Node* null = new Node();
    null->set_fr(0);
    null->set_val(-1);

    while(getline(file, s)){
        istringstream buf(s);
        string s1;
        while(getline(buf, s1, ' ')){
            istringstream buf1(s1);
            int value;
            buf1 >> value;
            if(!check[value]){
                Node* new_node = new Node();
                new_node->set_val(value);
                new_node->set_fr(1);
                nodes.push_back(*new_node);
                check[value] = 1;
            } else {
                increment(nodes, value);
            }
        }
    }

    for(list<Node>::iterator it=nodes.begin(); it!=nodes.end(); it++){
        if(it->get_fr() < THRESHOLD){
            nodes.erase(it);
            it--;
        }
    }
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(ios::beg);

    while(getline(file, s)){
        cout << "Please Wait..." << endl;
        istringstream buf(s);
        string s1;
        list<int> values;
        while(getline(buf, s1, ' ')){
            istringstream buf1(s1);
            int value;
            buf1 >> value;
            values.push_back(value);
        }
        prune(nodes, values);
        sort_list(nodes, values);
        print_list(values);
        insert_into_tree(tree, header, null, values);
    }
    cout << "printing head" << endl;
    for(map< Node*, list<Node*> >::iterator it=tree.begin(); it!=tree.end(); it++){
        print_node(*it->first);
        cout << "children : ";
        for(list<Node*>::iterator jt=it->second.begin(); jt!=it->second.end(); jt++){
            Node* x = *jt;
            cout << x->get_val() << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool compare(const Node& first, const Node& second){
    if(first.get_fr() > second.get_fr()){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

void increment(list<Node> &nodes, int &value){
    for(list<Node>::iterator it = nodes.begin(); it!=nodes.end(); it++){
        if(it->get_val() == value){
            it->inc_fr();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void print_list(list<int> a){
    cout << "item set ";
    for(list<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it!=a.end(); it++){
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void print_node(Node a){
    cout << "item " << a.get_val() << endl;
    cout << "frequency " << a.get_fr() << endl;
}

void prune(list<Node> &nodes, list<int> &values){
    for(list<int>::iterator it=values.begin(); it!=values.end(); it++){
        if(get_fr(nodes, *it) < THRESHOLD){
            values.erase(it);
            it--;
        }
    }
}

void sort_list(list<Node> &nodes, list<int> &values){
    for(list<int>::iterator it=values.begin(); it!=values.end(); it++){
        for(list<int>::iterator jt=values.begin(); jt!=values.end(); jt++){
            if(get_fr(nodes, *it) > get_fr(nodes, *jt)){
                swap(*it, *jt);
            } else if(get_fr(nodes, *it) == get_fr(nodes, *jt)){
                if(*it>*jt){
                    swap(*it, *jt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int get_fr (list<Node> nodes, int val){
    int fr;
    bool found = false;
    for(list<Node>::iterator it=nodes.begin(); it!=nodes.end(); it++){
        if(it->get_val() == val){
            found = true;
            fr = it->get_fr();
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        return fr;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

void insert_into_tree(map< Node*,list<Node*> > &tree, map< int, Node* > &header, Node* head, list<int> values){
    if(header.find(head->get_val()) == header.end()){
        header[head->get_val()] = head;
    } else{
        Node* new_head = header[head->get_val()];
        new_head = new Node();
        while(new_head != NULL){
            new_head = new_head->get_link();
        }
        new_head->set_link(head);
    }
    if(values.empty()) return;
    Node* node;
    if(find_head(tree, head)){
        bool found = false;
        for(list<Node*>::iterator it=tree[head].begin(); it!=tree[head].end(); it++){
            node = *it;
            if(node->get_val() == values.front()){
                node->inc_fr();
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            node = new Node();
            node->set_val(values.front());
            node->set_fr(1);
            tree[head].push_back(node);
        }
    } else{
        node = new Node();
        node->set_val(values.front());
        node->set_fr(1);
        tree[head].push_back(node);
    }
    values.pop_front();
    insert_into_tree(tree, header, node, values);
}

bool find_head(map< Node*,list<Node*> > tree, Node* head){
    bool found = false;
    for(map< Node*,list<Node*> >::iterator it=tree.begin(); it!=tree.end(); it++){
        Node* node = &*it->first;
        if(node->get_val() == head->get_val()){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

I am getting the error in the set_link function.

Comment: Show your actual code of creating Node object.

Comment: You saw that `this->link = new Node();` has `this->link` overwritten just after

Comment: Okay I have removed the line - this->link = new Node();

Comment: Damn it, `Show your actual code of creating Node object`, not whole code! Remove anything not helpful.

Comment: You're using many invalid iterators - `erase(it)` invalidates `it`. You should use `it = erase(it)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, no its alright

Comment: @eddard.stark No, it's not - it makes the program undefined and invalid.

Comment: I know what i am doing, thanks for your concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this function:

```
void set_link(Node* link){
    this->link = new Node();
    this->link = link;
}
```

you assign `this->link` twice, first time with a newly created pointer to `Node`, and the second time with `link` parameter, so what happens:

1. The pointer created with `new` is lost, leading to memory leak.
2. Perhaps elsewhere in the code you call `delete node` for the node you previously passed as parameter to `set_link` function, so `this->link` becomes invalid, and when you try to access the data through it, segfault happens.

Also the reason for segfault can be that `this` is invalid at the time of invocation of `set_link` (for example deleted previously or null).

EDIT: and indeed, it's null in your code.

Comment: I have remove the line this->link = new Node(); Still giving me the same error.

Comment: @eddard.stark that means you `delete` the pointer somewhere, as I supposed in p.2

Comment: I get the seg fault error right in this line this->link = link;

Comment: @eddard.stark add the code causing segfault to your question